# free(): invalid next size (normal) on fclose. But not when Valgrind runs

Tags: c, crash, valgrind

The code below breaks on the `fclose()` call.

```
void output_gauss_transform(char* filename, char* mode, double** T, 
                            double shift, int len)
{
    FILE* fp;

    printf("Outputting gauss transform to %s.\n", filename);

    if ((fp = fopen(filename, mode)) == NULL){
    perror("Could not open file");
    return;
    }

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    fprintf(fp, "%lf %lf\n", T[0][i], T[1][i] + shift);
    }

    if (fclose(fp)){
    printf("error closing\n");
    }
}
```

`glibc` gives me this error, along with the memory map.

```
*** glibc detected *** [sourcedir]/.libs/lt-launcher: free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0821da38 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x75ee2)[0xb739dee2]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(fclose+0x154)[0xb738d424]
/src/.libs/libfile_util.so.0(output_gauss_transform+0xa9)[0xb77b5859]
/src/.libs/lt-launcher[0x804a0f9]
/src/.libs/lt-launcher[0x804a2a5]
/src/.libs/lt-launcher[0x804983b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3)[0xb73414d3]
/src/.libs/lt-launcher[0x8049915]
```

When attempting to debug this with `valgrind`, I get no errors whatsoever, with it outputting the following. What is going on?

```
==30396== HEAP SUMMARY:
==30396==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==30396==   total heap usage: 1,059 allocs, 1,059 frees, 78,149 bytes allocated
==30396== 
==30396== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==30396== 
==30396== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==30396== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

edit: Running `valgrind` with `-v`, I get this thing at the end. Perhaps it has something to do with what is going on?

```
 --31325-- REDIR: 0x454cac0 (operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x402bb98 (operator delete(void*))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code is the *victim*, you need to find the perpetrator. When you call `fclose`, some structure is freed. At that point, the code discovers that the free pool is corrupt and reports an error. However, it's some other chunk of code that corrupted the free pool, not this code.

The most common causes of this error are freeing the same block of memory twice and accessing a block of memory after you've freed it. It's strange that `valgrind` wasn't able to catch this, since these are exactly the kind of errors it usually catches.

Comment: Are there any switches that I can use to make Valgrind even stricter with its checks?

Comment: Have a look at `--redzone-size` and `--freelist-vol`. Does your program do anything strange itself with memory allocations? (For example, get an object from a library that it then has to free, implement its own "re use recently freed objects" behavior, or something like that?)