# Error in 'a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c++, gcc, file-io

I'm writing a big application and i recently included there my new module for working with files. It has simple functions of writing integers and strings, it was tested to be perfect on Red Hat. It does exactly what i want.

Here's the implementation of the functions there:

```
int CFile_open(CFile* owner, char* filename, char* mode) {
    owner->file = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (owner->file == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int CFile_close(CFile* owner) {
    if (owner->file == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (fclose(owner->file) ) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int CFile_writeInt(CFile* owner, int num) {
    if (owner->file == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        if (fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), 1, owner->file)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int CFile_writeString(CFile* owner, char* str) {
    if (owner->file == NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        char b = strlen(str);
        if (fwrite(&b, sizeof(char), 1, owner->file)) {
            for (int i=0; i<=b; i++) {
                fwrite(&str[i], sizeof(char), 1, owner->file);
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

These functions are being used in the wrapper-function and then being executed in my application.
Here's that function:

```
void fileWrite(void* data) {
    CList* list = (CList*)data;
    CNode* node = list->first;
    CData* info = NULL;
    CFile* f = (CFile*)malloc(sizeof(CFile));
    f->init = CFile_init;
    f->init(f);

    if (list->length == 0) {
        printf("%s\n", "The list is empty!");
        wait();
    } else {
        int i = 1;

        if (f->open(f, (char*)"./f", (char*)"w")) {
            while (node) {
                info = node->getData(node);

                if (f->writeInt(f, info->getNum(info))) {
                    if (f->writeString(f, info->getAdr(info))) {
                        if (f->writeString(f, info->getPh(info))) {
                            printf("%s%d\n", "Wrote item #", i);
                            i++;
                        } else {
                            printf("%s%d\n", "Error writing Phone of item #", i);
                        }
                    } else {
                        printf("%s%d\n", "Error writing Adress of item #", i);
                    }
                } else {
                    printf("%s%d\n", "Error writing Number of item #", i);
                }

                node = node->next;
            }
            if (f->close(f)) {
                printf("%s\n", "Wrote successfully");
                wait();
            }
        }
        free(f);
    }
}
```

The problematic spot is the `f->close(f)` at the very end of the function.
If i don't close the file, everything works flawlessly. But if i do, i'm getting the following error:

```
*** Error in 'a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x0859c320 ***
```

However, despite the application crash, it does close the file, and the info i wrote to it is correct and not corrupted.

But i can't figure out why am i getting the error. I close the file only once (as you may see from the function), and i also tried commenting the `free(f)` line.
Also if i call `fclose(f->file)` there i get the same error, so that's not the `close()` function issue.

I assume that the rest of the application works (and worked before i added the function) perfectly except for the line where i close the file.

The reason i mentioned RedHat is because it was working perfectly there, but when i recompiled it under ArchLinux (also tried Debian) - it won't close the file. Same compiler versions were used everywhere.

I compile it with `g++` if that matters, but i also have the same issue with `clang++`.

I also tried running it with `valgrind` and it says nothing about files, or i just couldn't find the right keys for that. Perhaps you know?

So do you have any ideas on what's going on and how to fix it? I was staring at the code for literally 3 hours already and i can't figure it out for the life of me.

---

Test case:

`info->getNum()` returns integer "11" (assigned during input)
`info->getAdr()` returns dynamically allocated char array "aa" (allocated and assigned during input)
`info->getPh()` returns dynamically allocated char array "bb" (allocated and assigned during input)

I can test these values using other functions in my application, so i'm 100% confident they are correct.

Then i just evoke the `fileWrite()` function.

Comment: Present your _testcase_.

Comment: It's hard to suggest something useful without seeing what the `CFile` member functions do.

Comment: Edited the question. I don't know if that would help because the only things i'm getting from outside the function are the values that i can check and i'm sure they are correct.

Comment: R Sahu, the `CFile` functions are listed in the first code block of the post.

Comment: What if you comment out while loop, leaving only opening and closing file?

Comment: Tomashu, no, it's still the same. All the `CList` related operations are most probably correct as well. However i only create one `CNode` in my application while testing and `CList::first` points to that single `CNode`, so there might not be an error.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14636125/867354

Comment: Tomashu, i googled before asking, and i've seen this one (it made me download valgrind), but i couldn't apply it to my case. I don't allocate anything after closing the file. Following the application scenario, all there's after the end of this function is a bunch of `printf()`s and a single `scanf()`.

Comment: It have to be before closing. Heap/stack corruption often crash in weird locations, completly unrelated.

Comment: This is tagged as `c++` but it looks more like C with a home-rolled object oriented programming approach... is C++ the correct tag?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm just being a freak.

Comment: Tomashu, hm, i will double check the code before the close then. However, after the crash, it does it's job. It writes correct info to a correct file in a correct order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a first glance:

In `CFile_writeString` there's an off-by-one error. `for (int i=0; i<=b; i++)` should terminate at `i<b`. The `&str[b]` will result in undefined behaviour.

BTW, result type of `strlen` is `size_t`, not `char`.

I don't know if that's the cause of your problem, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I fixed it. But, apparently, the issue still persists.

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` to leverage compiler diagnostics and fix all warnings. If that still does not resolve your issue try to reduce the test case to a minimal example needed to reproduce the problem (see [http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: I've seen your post over at reddit and had a look at [https://bitbucket.org/owyou/simplebd](https://bitbucket.org/owyou/simplebd). One additional issue: You reserve space for 5 menu items, but call `CMenu_addItem` 6 times, resulting in another off-by-one accessing `owner->list[len]`.

Comment: Fixing the one with the list eliminated the error. Thanks for noticing. I'm always getting confused about array indexes when i also need to handle the user input.

Comment: I have a similar problem, checked answer here and found out I also have a similar boundary issue. Thanks guys